# SQL returns wrong order

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use SQL to build up a class of objects for future use in my apps. Basically you pass it through a table name and it'll return you the syntax for the class to paste in to c#

It works to a point, but some of the items are returned in a weird order:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @TableName ='Users'

select 'public class obj_' + @TableName + '{'
union

SELECT 'public '+ CASE WHEN t.name IN ('int', 'bigint') THEN 'Int32'
            WHEN t.name IN ('nvarchar','varchar','text','ntext') THEN 'String'
            WHEN t.name IN ('datetime','smalldatetime') THEN 'DateTime'
            WHEN t.name IN ('decimal') THEN 'Decimal'
            WHEN t.name IN ('bit') THEN 'Boolean'
            ELSE 'Unknown' END
+ ' ' + c.name + '{ get; set; }' FROM syscolumns as c

JOIN systypes t ON t.xusertype=c.xusertype
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name=@TableName) 
union
Select '}'
```

It returns it like:

```
}
public Boolean IsAdmin{ get; set; }
public class obj_Users{
public Int32 UserCompanyID{ get; set; }
public Int32 UserID{ get; set; }
public Int32 UserRole{ get; set; }
public String Email{ get; set; }
public String FirstName{ get; set; }
public String SessionKey{ get; set; }
public String Surname{ get; set; }
public String UserName{ get; set; }
public String UserPassword{ get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: Without an ORDER BY, there is no defined order for the resulting rows.

Comment: What do you mean "wrong"? There is no ORDERBY of any kind in your code, so not sure what makes one of arbitrary orders "correct".

Comment: Also, you're trying to solve a problem that has been solved a million times before. You want an ORM by the looks of it.

Comment: Sorry, i assumed the union would bring the closing bracket to the bottom? Also, why is the Boolean one higher, because alphabetical?

Comment: UNION statements don't ORDER. They Group.

Comment: read up on `SQL SERVER ORDER BY Clause`

Comment: Also, stop wasting your time on this problem, please... There are so many existing, tried and tested solutions to code/schema generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ordering by `colid`.  This is a bit of a challenge given your query, but this will probably work:

```
select 'public class obj_' + @TableName + '{'
union all
(SELECT 'public '+ CASE WHEN t.name IN ('int', 'bigint') THEN 'Int32'
            WHEN t.name IN ('nvarchar','varchar','text','ntext') THEN 'String'
            WHEN t.name IN ('datetime','smalldatetime') THEN 'DateTime'
            WHEN t.name IN ('decimal') THEN 'Decimal'
            WHEN t.name IN ('bit') THEN 'Boolean'
            ELSE 'Unknown' END
+ ' ' + c.name + '{ get; set; }' FROM syscolumns as c

JOIN systypes t
     ON t.xusertype=c.xusertype
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name=@TableName) 
ORDER BY colid)
union all
Select '}'
```

A more robust solution is to use subqueries:

```
select str
from ((select -1 as ordering, 'public class obj_' + @TableName + '{' as str
      union all
      (SELECT colid,
             'public '+
              (CASE WHEN t.name IN ('int', 'bigint') THEN 'Int32'
                   WHEN t.name IN ('nvarchar','varchar','text','ntext') THEN 'String'
                   WHEN t.name IN ('datetime','smalldatetime') THEN 'DateTime'
                   WHEN t.name IN ('decimal') THEN 'Decimal'
                   WHEN t.name IN ('bit') THEN 'Boolean'
                   ELSE 'Unknown'
               END) + ' ' + c.name + '{ get; set; }'
       FROM syscolumns c JOIN
            systypes t
            ON t.xusertype=c.xusertype
       WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = @TableName) 
      ) union all
      (Select 10000, '}')
     )
ORDER BY ordering
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your help. The subqueuries makes more sense I guess going forward, however it doesn't seem to like the order by part 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'